# How to unit test file uploading?

Tags: unit-test, upload, files

The code as written below uploads a file to salesforce, then redirects the user to a specific page.

```
public class ContentController {

    public contentController() {
        file = new ContentVersion();
    }

    public ContentVersion file { get; set; }
    public PageReference go() {
        insert file;

        return new PageReference('** an example url**');
    }
}
```

How can I write an automated unit test to test "uploading a file"?  I don't quite get how to do so unless I somehow generate an anonymous file in apex [which only works with documents](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xWUIAY), but not all file types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to query the data to make sure it actually gets into the database. You should also test on the redirect.

```
MyController controller = new MyController();
controller.file.Body = Blob.valueOf('populated');

Test.startTest();
    PageReference redirect = MyController.go();
Test.stopTest();

system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() FROM ContentVersion]);
// assert on redirect
```