# Body not a variable of ContentVersion?

Tags: unit-test, files, contentversion, blob

I am drafting up a couple of unit tests for [this code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204069/how-to-unit-test-file-uploading).

Here is what the code looks like so far:

```
public class ContentController {

    public ContentController() {
        file = new ContentVersion();
    }

    public ContentVersion file { get; set; }
    public PageReference go() {
        insert file;
        return new PageReference('**url**');
    }
}
```

The initial unit test for testing just a file upload for this code is drafted up as such:

```
@isTest
private class BestDoctorsTest{
    @isTest
    private static void testUpload(){
        ContentController controller = new ContentController();
        controller.file.Body = Blob.valueOf('populated');
        PageReference redirect = controller.go();
        system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() FROM ContentVersion]);
    }
}
```

Given how [Blobs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm) work and the functionality of [ContentVersions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) this should work fine.  However, apex returns this error:
[image]

How to I correctly obtain the body of a ContentVersion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For ContentVersion, the property that contains the blob data is 'VersionData'.  Line 6 should be changed to:

```
controller.file.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('populated');
```

See more here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Yes, welcome! Looks like you're off to a solid start :)